# Split Array into multiple Array and store in different variables

Tags: php

I want to divide below given array and store it in different variable.For eg.$array1,$array2,$array3.Any help would be grateful.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => PVTHR05L006
                [1] => PVTHR05L004
                [2] => PVTS1K05L004
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => PVTHR05L004
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => PVTHR05L006
                [1] => PVTHR05L004
                [2] => PVTSK05L008
            )

    )
```

My expected output is

```
$array1 = Array
        (
            [0] => PVTHR05L006
            [1] => PVTHR05L004
            [2] => PVTS1K05L004
        ); $array2 = Array
        (
            [0] => PVTHR05L004
        ); $array3 = Array
        (
            [0] => PVTHR05L006
            [1] => PVTHR05L004
            [2] => PVTSK05L008
        );
```

Comment: What is the expected output? And where exactly did you got stuck while coding?

Comment: @Akhil add to question, not as a comment

Comment: Why don't try: `$array1 = $mainArr[0]` and so on.

Comment: It is in for loop.How can I store it accordingly.

Comment: DO you need answer??? Why don't you try yourself?

Comment: What's the use of storing it in different variables? If we do this dynamically, the variable names will be generated dynamically and you won't be able to access them directly without checking them first. Please specify your requirement.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator, I think i got him, He want to make some dynamic array like `$array1, $array2,.....`. So i make an answer.

Comment: Users are supposed to post their code instead of dumping their questions on to someone else's shoulders and let it solve it for them. And they'd probably copy paste it blindly without understanding one bit. I'm afraid, but we're not supposed to entertain such users who absolutely make no effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you really don't know the logic- The main logic behind this is variables of variable. Assign two variable called `$arr_name` and `$incre`, the `$arr_name` will be use to create the dynamic array name with the help of `$incre`.

```
$mainArr = array(
            array('PVTHR05L006', 'PVTHR05L004', 'PVTS1K05L004'),
            array('PVTHR05L004'),
            array('PVTHR05L006', 'PVTHR05L004', 'PVTSK05L008'),
        );

$arr_name = 'array';
$incre = 1;
foreach($mainArr as $arr){
    ${$arr_name.$incre} = $arr;
    $incre++;
}

print_r($array2);
```

[Online Example](https://3v4l.org/PBDsj), click and see the output. If you need any further help let me know.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it? someone could answer it before you could.

Comment: @Plum, The problem is _Users are supposed to post their code instead of dumping their questions on to someone else's shoulders and let it solve it for them. And they'd probably copy paste it blindly without understanding one bit. I'm afraid, but we're not supposed to entertain such users who absolutely make no effort_ said by **Object_Manipulator** in comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arry = array(
    0 => array('a', 'b'),
    1 => array('c', 'd'),
    2 => array('e', 'f'),
    3 => array('g', 'h'),
    4 => array('i', 'j'),
    5 => array('k', 'l'),
    6 => array('m'),
    7 => array('n'),
    8 => array('o'),
    9 => array('p'),
   10 => array('q'),
   11 => array('r')
);


$i = 1;


foreach($arry as $val){

    $arr[$i] = $val;

    $i++;

}
print_r($arr[$i]);
```

Put the values inside a foreach assign to array keys 1,2,3. etc..